# DataTable.Copy() didnt copy the first row

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I tried to copy a datatable using this code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dat = dGV.DataSource as DataTable;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = dat.Copy();
    dGV.DataSource = dt;
}
```

But when I ran it, the first row wasnt copied. The result looks like this :

Before : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B--Fi4mWsFk5NXlJM0ZRSXhRbjA/view?usp=sharing

After : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B--Fi4mWsFk5OFptY2ZPRHlNaWc/view?usp=sharing

If I move the cursor into the second row before clicking the button it will copy all data including the first row. The data was imported from excel using this code :

```
private void importFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    dGV.DataSource = GetTable();
    string path = importFileDialog.FileName;
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
    if (ext == ".xlsx" | ext == ".xls")
    {
        try
        {
            string Excel03ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            string Excel07ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            string conStr, sheetName;
            conStr = string.Empty;
            switch (ext)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    conStr = string.Format(Excel03ConString, path);
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                    conStr = string.Format(Excel07ConString, path);
                    break;
            }

            //Get the name of the First Sheet.
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            //Read Data from the First Sheet.
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        oda.Fill(dt);
                        con.Close();

                        //Populate DataGridView.
                        //dGV.DataSource = dt;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
                        {
                            //dGV.RowCount++;
                            //dGV.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = dt.Row[i].;
                            for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; ++k)
                            {
                                dGV[k, i].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[k];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to read the file");
        }
    }
}
```

If I input the data manually everything works fine.

Comment: [C# MSDN DataTable.Copy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also looks like you are assigning the datasource to soon in the beginning of the method

Comment: Did you read first row?

Comment: also in your using there is no need to call the following `con.Close();` the `Fill` method will do the following `Open();` so there is no need to call the Open() method explicitly

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `clone function` try this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dat = (DataTable)dGV.DataSource;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = dat.Clone();
    dGV.DataSource = dt;
}
```

or

```
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)dGV.DataSource;
    dGV.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: And the difference with `Copy` is?

Comment: @MikeDebela Clone will take care of `constraints`

Comment: I tried but .Clone() didnt copy the value of the datatable. From Microsoft : "Copy creates a new DataTable with the same structure and data as the original DataTable. To copy the structure to a new DataTable, but not the data, use Clone."

Comment: @geeqy why are you doing this first casting DataSource to datatabe  and after making copy of it again assigning to the DataSource ?
while you can simply assing like this `DataTable dt= dat;` or this `DataTable dt =(DataTable)dGV.DataSource;`

Comment: @KhurramAli i was actually debugging my program. i planned to do something with the copy without changing the value in the original datatable. i just realized that it didnt copy the first row.